# How this inequality works?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of Malinowski inequality by reading [this](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/31002/minkowski.pdf) article. But I don't know how Holder’s Inequality holds. specifically I don't know how this part works:
[image]

It says by summing over $i = 1, . . .,n,$ we obtain the last inequality. But I don't know how. And where did the last inequality came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the following inequality: $xy \leq \dfrac{x^p}{p} + \dfrac{y^q}{q}$, with 
$x = \dfrac{|a_i|}{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}, y = \dfrac{|b_i|}{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}}$. Also:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{|a_i|^p}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^p}=1$. The same is true for the other part which involves the $|b_i|^p$'s.